# Calling C code from C++ with using extern "C"

Tags: c++

I have 3 files with me, one c++ file, main.cpp, one c file, test.c and one header file, test.h

I wanted to try and use C code into C++ file. For the same reason, I have declared an function in test.h and defined that in test.c and using that in main.cpp

main_temp.c is just for explanation.

test.h

```
void test(int);
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void test(int a) {
  printf("%d", a);
```

main_temp.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int main() {
  foo(5);
}
```

Here, I understand why this would not work. C symbol would be simple 'foo' but since C++ does more things while creating symbols, it might be 'void@test(int)' and to solve this name mangling problem, I have to treat C++ symbol as a C symbol. So, I would use extern "C" and my main.cpp becomes as like:

main.cpp

```
extern "C" {
  #include "test.h"
}
int main() {
  foo(5);
}
```

I could not understand as to why this would not work! I get :

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `test`
```

Can somebody share the insights?

Comment: Did you link with test.o, and how was it compiled? Show your command line steps, or your `Makefile`, or `CMakefile`, or etc. if you're using a build system.

Comment: @aschepler, I just did : g++ main.cpp

Comment: Then you are missing `test.c`

Comment: So test.c isn't even a part of that program, and the definition of `test` really is missing.

Comment: @aschepler, Alright. I did g++ main.cpp test.c and it gave me the same error.

Comment: (Also, I hope you mean "g++ -Wall main.cpp". Always turn on more than the default warnings; many of the -Wall warnings can find serious mistakes for you.)

Comment: @aschepler, with g++ -Wall main.cpp test.c , It stays the same.

Comment: @HemantBhargava You shouldn't use the `g++` frontend to compile C files.  You need to compile test.c with `gcc` and main.cpp with `g++` and then link them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I trust you compile or link them together? Else that would be the cause. On gcc it would be something like:

```
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
gcc -c -o test.o test.c
g++ -o a.out main.o test.o
```

Assuming you have no bugs with compiling/linking, compile both main.cpp and test.c into object files and run `nm` on both. It will show what symbol `main.o` wants and what symbol `test.o` exports. It should become clear then why linker cannot do its job.

Comment: Lowercase `-c`. (And you can omit the `-o x.o` if you don't want a different filename or different output directory; the default is to use the same filename replacing the extension with `.o`)

Comment: I understand. Isn't there any way rather compile only two? Why do we need to compile separately for C and C++ files? Why can not I just do: g++ main.cpp test.c?

Comment: `g++ main.cpp test.c` will compile test.c as C++, not C.

Comment: g++ is the driver for the C++ compiler, but you can tell it to switch to a different language instead: `g++ main.cpp -x c test.c`. The `-x` flag means "files later on the command line use this specific language".

Comment: @MilesBudnek • For C, you should use a C compiler.  For C++, you should use a C++ compiler.  If you were to have FORTRAN in the mix, the for FORTRAN you should use a FORTRAN compiler.

Comment: Aah. Great. I understand. Thanks to all.